# ios and html5 application cache testing

Tags: android, ios, html, caching

How can I see what's in the application cache on an iOS device or on an Android device?

In the desktop chrome browser (12) in the console you can see all "Application Cache event" so at least you have a vague idea that it is working.

Comment: have you tried just turning WiFi/3G off and seeing what displays?

Comment: yes, i did, but i'd like to see exactly what's content of the cache

Answer (score 0):

Web Inspector in Safar 5.1 developer version has a nice UI for the application cache.